# ReactiveX in REST API without UI

Tags: rx-java, observer-pattern, reactivex

I'm starting to study ReactiveX and couldn't understand the advantages in a REST API, or any api that doesn't have a UI associated.

For instance, I'm building a Spring Boot REST API that is consumed by a Angular webapp (and eventually other apps) that is hosted on a different machine. Whenever I send a request from the webapp I'll use promises to handle the result without blocking.

So it that case, does it make sense to use ReactiveX (RxJava in that case) in the Spring Boot application? What advantages would it bring?

Answer (score 1):

With ReactiveX you can do different calls asyncronous at the same time and when all these calls are done you do something (like dissmiss progressbar ) and to do that you must use the zip operator : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

You can make also perform asyncronous tasks one after the other. you can filter the first call and give its response to the second. You can do this by filter and FlatMap operators :

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html

Comment: On a pure REST API where I'm basically performing only CRUD operations, I should not need to perform parallel tasks therefore ReactiveX is not helpful ,is that right?

Comment: You may perform parallel CRUD operations from your REST API, like display a dashboard containing a list of groups and list of persons of a classroom.You shoud do two parralel tasks , get all persons + get all groupes. once you get the result you display the dashbord. another example of using flatmap operation, you may use an asyncronous crud task as an input parameter to perform another asyncronous  crud task

Comment: I still think a better approach for your dashboard example is for the UI to make two parallel requests (using promises), the server would handle those separately (tomcat creates a thread per request), and then using sometihng like Promise.all to show the dashboard after both completed. The server would not gain in using ReactiveX. But I think things are clearer now.